# Realm 4.1.1 CannotCompileException

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, realm

I've done all the steps in order to add Realm to my project.

1.Added the plugin to my Project build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.1.1"}
```

2.Added the following into my app build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
realm {
    syncEnabled = true
}
```

3.Added the following in my Application Class file:

```
Realm.init(this);
    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().name("mDB.realm")
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
```

But when i try to run my app i get the following message:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForDebug'.
>   javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] realm$injectObjectContext() not found in io.realm.internal.RealmObjectProxy

Btw, I'm currently using Android Studio 3.0 Beta 6 in case this might be the problem.

Comment: Do you by chance have any other versions of Realm in your project (dependencies -> compile)? Because you shouldn't. Also, AS 3.0.0 stable is out, so you can upgrade to that if you want

Comment: I double checked and no,I don't have any other realm related dependencies.I'll try to update my AS and come back with the result

Comment: I still get the same error message

Comment: Do you apply any other plugins? For example, `kotlin-android`?

Comment: nope, just these two  apply plugin: 'com.android.application' and
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

Comment: Unfortunately then I'm not sure, but if you can put a sample project on Github that can reproduce this then I'll look at it.